# How to add initial view to Storyboard file?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2, storyboard

I started an "Empty Application" template, this means that I had to add my own storyboard file.  Problem is, it is completely blank, and I can't figure out how to get the first view on there, so I can start designing my interface.

Anyone know how to get that first view on there?

Comment: It's insane that we have to look up this kind of basic, basic functionality. WTF, Apple?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you create a new Storyboard file, all you need to do is click/drag the UIViewController object from your right hand side of tools into your Storyboard and then you're all set to begin work on your new Storyboard.

Comment: What is "the UIViewController object from your right hand side of tools"? My files, including UIViewController files, are listed on the left, and I'm pretty sure that's normal.

Comment: This was a number of years ago, but the right hand pane I was referring to back then was the UI component list in Xcode that allowed you to add to UI elements to your storyboard (UIView, UILabel, etc etc).

Answer (score 11):

Just in case you can not start from scratch :

- Select your View Controller
- Open the **Attribute inspector** (right pan by default)
- Go to **View Controller** section
- Select **Is Initial View Controller** checkmark of the Initial Scene option

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In the latest version of Xcode (12.2), this is how you can add initial view to story board

[image]

Click on + Icon,

[image]

search "View Controller", Drag and drop View Controller.

Comment: I don't get it. Drag and drop from the Objects library does absolutely nothing for me - I've got one existing scene, and when I try to drop an object on the canvas next to it, it just doesn't work. Any idea what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: Just tried, it works for me. Can you share some screenshots?

Comment: holy ****, the + icon

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Edit->Show Library` then drag and drop a type of View Controller that you need.